# how to select columns from list dynamically in dataframe plus a fixed column

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java8.

I have  dynamic list of columns is are passed into my function.

i.e.

```
List<String> cols = Arrays.asList("col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4");
Dataset<Row> df = //which has above columns plus "id" ,"name" plus many other columns;
```

Need to select cols + "id" + "name"

I am doing as below

```
Dataset<Row> res_df = df.select("id", "name", cols.stream().toArray( String[]::new));
```

> this is giving compilation error. so how to handle this use-case.

**Tried :**

When I do something like below :

```
List<String> cols = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4"));
cols.add("id");
cols.add("name");
```

**Giving error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
```

Comment: You get `UnsupportedOperationException` because actual type of List you're using is `Arrays.ArrayList` (returned from `Arrays.asList`) and not `util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of ways to achieve this, relying on different `select` method signatures.

One of the possible solutions, with the assumption `cols` List is immutable and is not controlled by your code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import scala.collection.JavaConverters;

public class ATest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .master("local[2]")
                .getOrCreate();

        List<String> cols = Arrays.asList("col_1", "col_2");

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql("select 42 as ID, 'John' as NAME, 1 as col_1, 2 as col_2, 3 as col_3, 4 as col4");
        df.show();

        ArrayList<String> newCols = new ArrayList<>();
        newCols.add("NAME");
        newCols.addAll(cols);
        df.select("ID", JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(newCols.iterator()).asScala().toSeq())
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BdEngineer I've updated the post with a full working example.

Answer (score 1):

You could create array of Columns and pass it to the select statement.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

List<String> cols = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4"));
cols.add("id");
cols.add("name");
Column[] cols2 = cols.stream()
        .map(s->new Column(s)).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toArray(new Column[0]);

settingsDataset.select(cols2).show();
```

Comment: try to change List to ArrayList<String> cols and add these imports `import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;`